# how to build a delay synchronized to clock?

Tags: reaktor

Please give me any Basic Idea or some tutorial which is helpful.

I really dont understand what to put in for a clock.

Thank you

Comment: You need to explain this better. What type of clock, delay and for what purpose. We are not mind readers.

Comment: It should be a simple clock, and Im experimenting in Reaktor.

Comment: Why type of clock? A sync clock, an alarm clock? You are not making it easy for us..